# How to calculate quotient $A/(0)$ and $A/A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

What is the procedure or to calculate ( or simplify, I'm new in abstract algebra) a quotient group? I know that $A$ a group and $B$ a subgroup we can form the quotient $$A/B $$
for example $$ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}  \cong  \mathbb{Z_n} $$

but how to know it?

Comment: *NB:* $B$ must be normal in $A$.

Comment: @Shaun what if not?

Comment: Then one would have to specify which cosets one is using, left or right, since normality of $B$ in $A$ is equivalent to $aB=Ba$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: $A/(0)$ is isomorphic to $A$ and $A/A$ has one element

Comment: Why $A/A$ as one element?

Comment: Because the elements of $G/H$ when $H$ is a normal subgroup are the cosets $gH = \{gh\mid h\in H\}.$ The group is partitioned into distinct cosets, and when $H = G,$ the only coset is $G$ itself. One checks that $gG = G$ for any $g\in G,$ so that there is one distinct coset.

Comment: @Stahl so $A/A \cong A ?$

Comment: No, $A/A = \{A\}\cong\{e\}\cong 0.$

Comment: but $ A \cong A$ isn't? why ${A} \cong {e} $ ?

Comment: Calculations and theorems follow from definitions. What is your definition of a quotient group?

Comment: @JoséMarín it's not $A\cong e$, its $\{A\}\cong \{e\}$, Two groups with one element are isomorphic. The first has $A$ as only element and the other one has $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is a normal subgroup of $A$, the set for the quotient group $A/B$ consists of cosets of $B$ in $A,$

i.e., {$aB | a\in A$}.

If $B=A$, then this is {$aA|a\in A$}, which is simply {$A$}.

If $B=${$0$}, then this is {$a | a\in A$}, which is simply $A$.

Thus, $A/A$ is a group with one element (i.e., $A$), and $A/${$0$} is isomorphic to $A$.

When $A$ is finite, |$A/B|=|A|/|B|;$

in particular, $|A/A|=|A|/|A|=1$ and $|A/${$0$}$|=|A|/1=|A|$.